# Venus Exploration

Tags: venus, terraforming

While reading an article about a possible ["Cloud City" on Venus](https://www.foxnews.com/science/nasa-eyes-stunning-cloud-city-airship-concept-to-explore-venus) I was taken by the following statement:

> Venus’s atmosphere is mainly carbon dioxide and thick clouds of
>   sulfuric acid cover the entire planet. “The atmosphere traps the small
>   amount of energy from the sun that reaches the surface along with the
>   heat the planet itself releases,” NASA explains. “This greenhouse
>   effect has made the surface and lower atmosphere of Venus one of the
>   hottest places in the solar system.”

If Venus's atmosphere is 'mainly' carbon dioxide and plants process CO2 into O2 what would happen if we just dumped an **enormous** amount of plant life onto Venus? (of course aiming to no land in a lava plain... say on top of a mountain). Would the plants be able to begin the process of creating an sustainable oxygen rich atmosphere?

Comment: Possibly relevant [Why not bring life to the atmosphere of Venus along with the next exploring mission?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27302/12978)